# Do electrons change their spin when interacting via virtual photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, photons, electrons, quantum-spin

As photons are spin-1 particles, and the electromagnetic force between two electric charged particles is mediated by virtual photons, does this mean that spin is also transfered? Like two free electrons interacting with each other, emiting and absorbing virtual photons, constantly changing its momentum. Is there also a constant change of each electrons spin state?

Comment: QED is a vectorlike interaction, so electron components preserve their chirality  at the interaction vertex.

Comment: Interacting with a photon may or may not flip the spin of an electron. Inspect the spin components of a Weyl spinor, which depend on mass and momentum.

Comment: Virtual photons in Moeller scattering carry circular polarization if the electrons are longitudinally polarized. Thus Moeller scattering can be used to measure electron beam polarization. In unpolarized scattering (at tree level), the virtual photon can also have longitudinal polarization (unlike real photons). In deep inelastic scattering, this is the basis of the Rosebluth Separation.